# When is a critical point a local minimum?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let $f:R^n\to R$ be a strictly convex function. Suppose also that $f\in C^1(R^n)$. If $x^*\in R^n$ satisfies $\nabla f(x^*)=0$, show that $f$ has a local minimum at $x^*$.

I only know the second derivative test, but here $f$ is only $C^1$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: what does "strictly convex" mean?

Comment: $f$ does not need to be strictly convex, just convex will do. If $f$ is convex & $C^1$, then $f(x)-f(y) \ge Df(y)(x-y)$. Strictness allows you to conclude that the minimiser is unique.

Comment: I’ve got it. Thanks!

Comment: @copper.hat One question though. Even if it’s strictly convex, when we take t goes to 0 to get the derivative, how do we know the strict inequality won’t become non-strict inequality?

Comment: (1) You can't. (2) Why would you care? Strictness is only relevant here to show uniqueness, which you have not mentioned.

Comment: @copper.hat My misunderstanding. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiable strict convex implies convex differentiable. Then

$$f(y)\geq f(x)+<\nabla f(x), x-y> , \quad \forall y, x\in R^n$$

replacing $x=x^{*}$ you will find $$ f(y)\geq f(x^{*}), \quad\forall y \in R^n$$

Comment: Where are you getting the $h$ from? There was no uniformity specified in the question.

Comment: I fix my answer. The book where I see this property is https://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Lectures-Convex-Optimization-Applied/dp/1402075537

Comment: Strict convexity just means that $f(tx+(1-t)y) < 1 f(x)+(1-t) f(y)$ for $t \in (0,1), x \neq y$. What you seem to be presuming is something stronger.

Comment: I had forgot the exact forma of the inequality. Sorry.

Comment: You don't need the $h$ to show that $x^*$ is a global $\min$.

Comment: The strictly convexity guarantees the existence of a unique global minimum solution $x^{*}$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but, as I have already said, you only need strict convexity to conclude that, not the stronger version you are using above.

Comment: Ok, but I prefer to use the hypothesis given to find more general results when this is allowed. This result above is a property of strictly convex and differentiable function.

Comment: Your statement above is correct, but you are making a **much** stronger assumption than strong convexity. So when you write that you are using the hypothesis given, well, that is not correct. I have more than a passing familiarity with convexity.

Comment: Hum, I understand your point. Strictly is not strongly.

Comment: To illustrate, $f(x) = x^2$ is strictly convex, but there is no $h>0$ such that the above holds at $x^*=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote strongly when I meant strictly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another, more geometric proof.

Since $0$ is a subgradient of $f$, we see that the epigraph $\operatorname{epi} f $ lies above the hyperplane $H=\{(x,f(x^*))| x \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$ and intersects at $(x^*,f(x^*))$. In particular, $x^*$ is a global minimiser.

Since $f$ is strictly convex, so is $\operatorname{epi} f$, and hence can only intersect $H$ at one point. Hence $x^*$ is the unique global minimiser.